# Getting NullpointeException

Tags: android

Guys can you check it why i am getting a null pointer exception in this line,

```
cl = Class.forName(myClass);
```

Here's the code:

```
private void addBookmark(String[] values_array) {       
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.single_bookmark, null);

    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_text);
    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_button);

    text.setText(values_array[1]);

    final String myClass = values_array[0];
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Class<?> cl = null;
            try {
            cl = Class.forName(myClass); // <--- this is where i am getting a null pointer exception
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, cl);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

how should I fix that?
Or is there something I need to replace?

Comment: "in this line" - what line???

Comment: are you 100% positive that `myClass` isn't null?

Comment: You **really** should not use a single `String[]` to hold **different kinds of data** together! The first element is a classname, the second is a label kind: you should have a `private void addBookmark(String label, String className) {` signature for this method! The single array is ureadable, unstructured, generally unmaintainable!

Comment: This line only means that your string myClass is null .

Comment: can you give me example on how to do that? @ppeterka,.

Comment: what is `myClass`..????

Answer (score 0):

Java Docs says what Class.forName(); will return ClassNotFoundException if the class cannot be found so I'd say it never returns null.

See your logs.
May be java cannot find class by name from

```
String myClass = values_array[0];
```

Comment: You just (absolutely correctly!) wrote that `Java Docs says what Class.forName(); will return ClassNotFoundException if the class cannot be found so I'd say it never returns null.` Why did you then write then in the next sentence `May be java cannot find class by name from`? If that was true, he'd get the exception logged 2 lines below, in the catch block

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Class<?> cl = null;
        try {
            Log.e("onClick", "myClass="+myClass);
        cl = Class.forName(myClass); // <--- this is where i am getting a null pointer exception
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Make sure "myClass" is not null;

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comment as an answer, requested by OP to clear it up>

You **really** should not use a single `String[]` to hold semantically different kinds of data together!

The first element is a *classname*, the second is a *label* semantic: you should have a signature for this method having them separate! The single array is ureadable, unstructured, generally unmaintainable!

(I also added a condition to check for null in classNAme here... I assume having className as null is a fatal error.)

```
private void addBookmark(String labelText, String className) {      
      //check className not to be null
      if(className==null) {
          //handle error somehow, log error, etc
          ...
          //no point in doing anything the listener, it would not do any good, just return
          return;
      }

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.single_bookmark, null);

    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_text);
    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_button);

    text.setText(labelValue); // variable "labelValue"

    final String myClass = className; //variable className
      //checking for null

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Class<?> cl = null;
            try {
            cl = Class.forName(myClass); 
              } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //this case should be handled better.
            }
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, cl);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Of course, when you call this method, you should also change the code from:

```
addBookmark(anArrayOfStrings);
```

To

```
addBookmark(myLabelValueString, myClassNameString);
```

Where myLabelValueString, myClassNameString are String variables containing the respective values.